# Допустима ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Подскажите на счёт следующего предложения, вторая запятая здесь нормальна?

> Что будет, если взрослому человеку часто вместо ходьбы, бежать?

Comment: Какой смысл (информация) вкладывается в *часто*? Может быть, на худой конец, *чаще*?

Comment: @shampar, чтобы дать понять, что не всегда. Это предложение придумал я, это краткий заголовок, а потом в описании вопроса поясняется момент про "часто".

Comment: Предлагаю вариант ещё более краткий — *50 плюс: с шага на бег*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вторая запятая не нужна:

***Что будет, если взрослому человЕку / часто вместо ходьбы бежать?***   (Показаны произносительная пауза и ударение при чтении.)

**Пояснение**

Обороты с предлогом "вместо" обособляются целиком или не обособляются вообще.

[Розенталь, пункт 3](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=116#pp116)

Существительные с предлогами или предложными сочетаниями ***кроме, вместо, помимо, сверх, за исключением, наряду*** с и др. (условно называемые дополнениями) могут обособляться или не обособляться.

Если предлог "вместо" имеет значения **‘за’, ‘взамен’,** то оборот с ним не обособляется: ***Вместо гнедого жеребца** Коржу дали толстого белого мерина* (Дик.); ***Вместо шубы** надел пальто; Пошёл на заседание **вместо заведующего***.

Comment: А можно какой-нибудь пример с предлогом "вместо", у которого НЕТ значений "за" и "взамен", а оборот с предлогом обособляется?

Comment: Из Розенталя: Оборот с предлогом вместо обособляется в двух случаях:

1) как дополнение, зависящее от глагола-сказуемого: Вместо весёлой петербургской жизни, ожидала меня скука в стороне глухой и отдалённой (П.) — оборот связан со сказуемым (‘и то и другое могло ожидать меня’); обособление факультативно;

2) как особая конструкция, не управляемая глаголом-сказуемым: Вместо ответа, Кириле Петровичу подали письмо (П.) — оборот синтаксически не связан со сказуемым, поскольку не образуется словосочетание подать ответ;

Comment: Вот еще: И отец с сыном, ВМЕСТО приветствия после долгой отлучки, начали насаживать друг другу тумаки (бить вместо приветствия).
ВМЕСТО ответа, он только взглянул на меня и отвернулся (грамматическое несоответствие: нет управления «взглянуть вместо»).

Comment: Понятно, спасибо!